# Duplicate symbol 'WixUI:WixUI_InstallDir' found

Tags: c#, .net, wix, wix-extension

I'm trying out with WiX and want to customize my UI. Therefore I added following two lines to my working WiX project:

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="dirInstall" />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
```

After that, i'll get the following error when trying to compile:

> Duplicate symbol 'WixUI:WixUI_InstallDir' found. This typically means
>   that an Id is duplicated. Check to make sure all your identifiers of a
>   given type (File, Component, Feature) are unique.

I'm pretty sure, that all my identifiers are unique, because without these two line it works.
So, what do I have to do so let it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving property id a different name. WixUI_InstallDir is predefined in wix toolsets and may be using that as property id might be causing the error.

Comment: this did not solve it for me.  if I changed WixUI_InstallDir to WixUI_InstallDir2 for example, I got another error WixUI_InstallDir2 is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

To Iterate on the answer above, if you are extending the WixUIExtension then you are asked to copy/paste the fragment which includes `<UI Id="WixUI_...">`, this reference conflicts with the one provided by the WixUIExtension, so you need to change both references.